# Call to undefined function insert_with_markers

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess

I'm experimenting with creating a function to write code into htaccess (I understand the security issues associated). I'm currently using the function [insert_with_markers()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/insert_with_markers/) as a starting point however its throwing a 'call to undefined function' error.

I am using it within a function that is only running whilst logged into the Admin Dashboard.

I understand that the function if found in the file: wp-admin/includes/misc.php but I made the assumption that this file is loaded whilst within the Admin Dashboard anyway, so I don't need to include it?

If I manually include the file, the function runs correctly.

**My question is:** does the wp-admin/includes/misc.php file not get loaded by default when logged in to the Dashboard? Or is it only loaded in certain cirumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `insert_with_markers()` function becomes available during `admin_init` hook. So in order for your code to work, you should do the following:

```php
function do_my_htaccess_stuff_371705() {
//function `insert_with_markers()` is working now
}

add_action('admin_init', 'do_my_htaccess_stuff_371705');
```

Comment: Can confirm - this solved the issue for me. I redesigned to code to let the add_action trigger my function and it allowed me to remove the include. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the source of the latest version, it shows that `misc.php` only gets included  in one place at `wp-admin/includes/admin.php`. The include there is unconditional. That file in turn gets included seemingly unconditionally in `wp-admin/admin.php`, and this is required unconditionally as the first line in `wp-admin/index.php`.

So it appears that it should be the case that's always available in the admin dashboard. If it's not, I'd suggest looking in more detail at what happens in `wp-admin/admin.php` in case something is going on there which bails out early.

EDIT: Note that PHP gives you the `require_once()` command which means that it's safe to include the file using require_once more than once, so you don't lose or risk anything going wrong by putting a require_once to that file in your code.

Comment: See above answer that worked for me but I appreciate the detail in your response, and I always overlook require_once function so that was a good reminder. Thank you!